# Counting characters in char array?

Tags: c, char

Currently i'm trying to sort a paragraph based on first char of each word. I'm initializing two alphabetic (Upper and Lower) char arrays to compare to the first char of the word to the array index.

My Plan for the problem;

- Initialize two Arrays with the Alphabet to know which alphabet goes before which.
- Have a function that actually compares first char to the two Arrays.
- return the words sorted :)

My problem is i'm trying to see if the two arrays have 26 characters to make sure every alphabet is counted for but it prints 1 and i have no idea why.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char _alphabetUpperCase[100] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R,","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    char _alpabetLowerCase[100] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while(_alpabetLowerCase[i] != NULL)
    {
        n = n+1;
        i++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This "A" is not same as 'A'. You should assign 'A' to a character instead.
Replace all "" strings with corresponding '' characters. e.g.

```
char _alpabetLowerCase[100] = {'a','b','c' ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

You want characters or strings? `"a"` is a string while `'a'` is a character. From your definition of array it seems you want characters. So change your code for that as

```
char _alpabetLowerCase[100] = {"a", ...
```

Instead use

```
char _alpabetLowerCase[100] = {'a', 'b', ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char _alphabetUpperCase[27] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R,','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z', '\0'};
    char _alphabetLowerCase[27] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z', '\0'};

    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while(_alphabetLowerCase[i] != '\0')
    {
        n = n+1;
        i++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation: `'a'` is char, but `"a"` is string. Also I added 27-th character to become sure that this loop will stop after `'z'` (so I changed the array size to 27 (100 was correct too, but it is wrong to write arbitrary numbers when you can put correct value)).